# flex4 - CheckBox and RadioButton validation

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

In my application i have both radio buttons and check boxes. Here I want to validate both CheckBox and RadioButton when I move to the next contol.

**Edit:**

My coding is here

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <s:RadioButtonGroup id="genderOption"/>

    <mx:StringValidator
        id="radioButtonValidator"
        source="{genderOption}"
        property="selectedValue"
        trigger="{groupLevel}"
        listener="{groupLevel}"
        required="true"
        requiredFieldError="field is required"/>

    <mx:StringValidator
        id="checkBoxValidation"
        source="qualificationGroup"
        required="true"
        property="selectedValue"
        listener="{qualificationGroup}"
        requiredFieldError="field is required"/>
</fx:Declarations>
<s:layout>
    <s:HorizontalLayout/>
</s:layout>

<mx:HDividedBox width="100%" height="100%">
    <s:Panel id="mainPanel" title="Employee Details" height="100%" width="50%">
        <s:Form id="mainForm" height="100%" width="100%" left="10%" right="10%" top="10%">
            <s:FormItem id="genderLabel" label="Gender" showErrorSkin="true" showErrorTip="false">              
                <s:HGroup id="groupLevel">
                    <s:RadioButton group="{genderOption}" label="Male" id="male" selected="false"/>
                    <s:RadioButton group="{genderOption}" label="Female" id="female" selected="false"/>
                </s:HGroup>
            </s:FormItem>
            <s:FormItem id="quaLabel" label="Qualification" showErrorSkin="true" showErrorTip="false">
                <s:HGroup id="qualificationGroup">
                    <s:CheckBox id="bsc" label="B.Sc"/>
                    <s:CheckBox id="be" label="BE"/>
                    <s:CheckBox id="mca" label="MCA"/>
                    <s:CheckBox id="mba" label="MBA"/>
                    <s:CheckBox id="others" label="Others"/>
                </s:HGroup>
            </s:FormItem>
        </s:Form>
    </s:Panel>  
</mx:HDividedBox>
```

And I am the new one for flex. If i am using change or click event, it will display the error message via alert box. But i don't want alert box. Is any other way to display the error message is there?

Comment: Can you give more info? What if you create a validate function and call it when the checkboxes and radio buttons are changed (listen for change event)

Comment: Sorry I can't help, I do not have experience with  this mx validators.2

Comment: okay. Thanks for reply. Please see this question [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21926042/how-to-remove-the-error-tip-and-error-icon-in-flex-4)

Answer (score 0):

When you move to the next control add and event listener to call a function to preform the validation checks.

Without more information i cant say which event listener will be applicable, but it will most likely be a click event.

```
<Script>
<![CDATA[
    protected function validate_HDivide(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        if(mycheckboxes.validate())
        {
            //do things
        }
        else
        {
            //display error
        }
    }
<s:HDividedBox id="mycheckboxes" change="validate_HDivide(event)"/>
<s:Button label="submit" click="validate_HDivide(event)"/>
```

then within your HDividedBox you can preform your validation

Thats how i would do it, hope this help.

Comment: I am having button group. But sorry, where i have to give change event? Please see my edit code.

Comment: I've edited my answer based on your edit code. Sorry its probably not the best answer as i am relatively new to flex myself

Comment: But I want to do this when I change the control from the HBox.

Comment: I'm sorry i don't know what you mean, in your code you aren't changing anything in the HBox, you are only trying to check the content which my solution allows.

Comment: In my code I have some other component too. I want to call the validate_HDivide(event) function when the Change event is occurred.

Comment: Ok, i have edited my answer to include a change event

Comment: okay. Thank you. I thing this change event is not possible for HGroup. Do you know which spark component will replace the HGroup? If you know that, My CheckBox validation will get over.

Comment: you can add change events to your radio buttons and check boxes, that would be the easiest way.